# Newtonian Mechanics - Find the acceleration of a particle on top of a wedge on top of a slope

Tags: trigonometry, classical-mechanics

Working through Introducing Mechanics, by Brian Jefferson and Tony Beadsworth. Question 5 of Exercise 5D has me a bit stumped. For some reason I get $\sqrt{3}$ times the result I want.

$\mathbf{The\;Question:}$

A smooth fixed plane is inclined at $30^{\circ}$ to the horizontal. A wedge of mass M and angle $30^{\circ}$ is held on the surface so that its upper face is horizontal, and a particle of mass $m$ rests on the face. The system is released from rest. Show that the resultant acceleration of the particle is $$\frac{(M+m)g}{4M+m}$$

Please find a picture of my working attached below, along with a bonus creepy silhouette of me pondering where it all went wrong.

$a$ is the acceleration of the wedge down the slope. $f$ is the acceleration of the particle on top of the wedge, $R$ (upwards) is the normal reaction of the wedge on the particle and $R$ downards is the normal reaction of the particle on the wedge. Using trigonometry, splitting forces into components and Newton's second law $F = ma$, I got the following 3 equations:
$$Mg \sin(30^{\circ}) + R \sin(30^{\circ}) = Ma$$
$$mg \sin(30^{\circ}) - R \sin(30^{\circ}) = m(f \cos(30^{\circ}) + a)$$
$$R \cos(30^{\circ}) - mg \cos(30^{\circ}) = mf\sin(30^{\circ})$$

Solving for $f$ I get $$f=\frac{-\sqrt{3}(M+m)g}{4M+m}$$

The negative (if correct) just means I got the direction of acceleration wrong in my diagram. But that $\sqrt{3}$ definitely shouldn't be there. Triple checked, and couldn't find anything wrong, which means there is a problem with the equations I used.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: My working.]

Comment: Why did you write $f\cos(30^{\circ}) + a$?

Comment: It seems to me, looking at the force diagram, the block will have a purely vertical acceleration $a$ (all forces are in the vertical direction). The wedge will have an acceleration $A$ purely parallel to the slope. There is no friction to keep the block moving with the wedge. I have 1 equation for the wedge (parallel to slope) and 1 equation for the block (vertical - which you can split up into 2 equations - parallel and perpendicular to the slope - but you have to be careful - you should have a cosine $60$ somewhere). I have 3 unknowns. There might be a relationship between $A$ and $a$

Comment: Hi DWade64, thanks a lot for that. It does make more sense that the acceleration of the block should be vertical, dunno what I was thinking - there are no horizontal forces acting on the block. Unfortunately I still can't really get anywhere with it, even after this improvement. Could you share with me the equations you have?

Comment: After some thought, I (surprisingly) got what they got. If you look at the force diagram, there are 3 forces on the wedge and 2 forces on the block, and 2 acceleration vectors. Everything except 1) the normal force on the wedge from the incline and 2) the acceleration of the wedge is in the up/down direction. Therefore, I choose an up/down, left/right coordinate system. I'd suggest trying that (your work above is with respect to the incline - It will work that way - though I haven't tried it out). You will get 3 equations. 1 equation for the block (vertical), 2 for the wedge (vert and horz)

Comment: You will have 4 unknowns: the 2 accelerations and the 2 normal forces. The trick to this problem is (assuming) that both objects fall at the same rate (they don't separate). Therefore the full (vertical) acceleration of the block $=$ the vertical acceleration component of the wedge

Comment: Letting $R_1$ be the normal reaction of the plane on the wedge, and $R_2$ the normal reaction of the wedge on the block, $f$ the downwards acceleration of the block and $a$ the acceleration of the wedge (parallel to the slope), were these the equations you got? $$m(f+asin(30)) = mg - R_2$$ $$Macos(30) = R_1sin30$$ $$f = asin(30)$$ $$Masin(30) = Mg + R_2 - R_1cos(30)$$:

Comment: Well, obviously those aren't your equations, because you got the right answer, lol. These 4 equations give $$f = \frac{(M+m)g}{4M+2m}$$ which is very close but no cigar. But those are all I can get out of it when I resolve everything horizontally and vertically. Guess I'm missing something important. Would really appreciate it if you could share your equations, then I can work backwards and figure out what it is that I'm missing.

Comment: Your 4 equations will give you the right answer if you use $mf = mg - R_2$ instead of your first equation. This should be the easiest equation to create. I would have written it as $mf = R_2 - mg$. Nevertheless, your 4 equations, with this change, will yield the right answer. My equations are essentially the same as yours. Where you have $f = a\sin(30)$, I have $f = a\cos(120)$. For your 2 other $\sin(30)$'s I had either a $\cos(60)$ or a $\cos(120)$. They are essentially the same equations, but in comparison to yours, I had negative's everywhere

Comment: Right! Because of no friction, the acceleration of the wedge actually has no component on the acceleration of the block, as you said earlier. Thank you so much for your help, really appreciate it. That problem was driving me mental!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the dynamics for each mass and also that the wedge is smooth

$$
m\vec \alpha_m = m\vec g + \vec V\\
M\vec\alpha_M = M\vec g-\vec V + \vec N\\
$$

with

$$
\vec\alpha_m = (0,a_m)\\
\vec g = (0,-g)\\
\vec V = (0, v)\\
\vec\alpha_M = (a_x,a_y)\\
\vec N = n(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)
$$

now solving for $n,a_x,a_y,a_m,v$

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 m a_m =v-g m \\
 a_x M= -n \sin \theta \\
 a_y M=-g M-v+n \cos \theta\\
 \frac{a_y}{a_x}=\tan\theta \\
 a_m=a_y \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

we get at

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 n & = & \frac{2 \sqrt{3} g M (m+M)}{m+4 M} \\
 a_x & = & -\frac{\sqrt{3} g (m+M)}{m+4 M} \\
 a_m& =& -\frac{g (m+M)}{m+4 M} \\
 a_y& =& -\frac{g (m+M)}{m+4 M} \\
 v& =& \frac{3 g m M}{m+4 M} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$